# How to speed up this string split operation within data.table

Tags: r, regex, string, split, data.table

I have a data.table with some IDs pasted together as a single character column, separated by underscores.  I'm trying to split the ids into separate columns, but my best method is really slow for my large dataset (~ 250M rows).  Interestingly, the operation doesn't appear to take O(N) time which is what I'd expect. In other words, it's pretty fast until about 50M+ rows and then gets really slow.

**Make some data**

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(2016)
sim_rows <- 40000000
dt <- data.table(
  LineId = rep("L0123", times=sim_rows),
  StationId = rep("S0123", times=sim_rows),
  TimeId = rep("T0123", times=sim_rows)
)
dt[, InfoId := paste(LineId, StationId, TimeId, sep="_")]
dt[, c("LineId", "StationId", "TimeId") := NULL]
gc(reset=T) # free up 1.5Gb of memory

dt
                     InfoId
       1: L0123_S0123_T0123
       2: L0123_S0123_T0123
       3: L0123_S0123_T0123
       4: L0123_S0123_T0123
       5: L0123_S0123_T0123
      ---                  
39999996: L0123_S0123_T0123
39999997: L0123_S0123_T0123
39999998: L0123_S0123_T0123
39999999: L0123_S0123_T0123
40000000: L0123_S0123_T0123
```

**Check timings**

```
system.time( dt[1:10000000, c("LineId", "StationId", "TimeId") :=
    tstrsplit(InfoId, split="_", fixed=TRUE)] )
 user  system elapsed 
5.179   0.634   3.867

system.time( dt[1:20000000, c("LineId", "StationId", "TimeId") :=
    tstrsplit(InfoId, split="_", fixed=TRUE)] )
 user  system elapsed 
7.805   0.958   7.703

system.time( dt[1:30000000, c("LineId", "StationId", "TimeId") :=
    tstrsplit(InfoId, split="_", fixed=TRUE)] )
  user  system elapsed 
12.556   1.782  12.349

system.time( dt[1:40000000, c("LineId", "StationId", "TimeId") :=
    tstrsplit(InfoId, split="_", fixed=TRUE)] )
  user  system elapsed 
29.260   2.822  29.895
```

**Check result**

```
dt
                     InfoId LineId StationId TimeId
       1: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
       2: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
       3: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
       4: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
       5: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
      ---                                          
39999996: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
39999997: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
39999998: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
39999999: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
40000000: L0123_S0123_T0123  L0123     S0123  T0123
```

How can I speed this baby up?

Comment: Obvious question - are the sections separated by `_` always the same length?

Comment: @thelatemail good question.  Unfortunately, no.

Comment: How many combinations are there relative to num rows? If that ratio is low, you can memoize with a join operation. If it's a primary key (ratio of 1), wouldn't help.

Comment: Heh, fread it? I might try that next time I'm near a computer.

Comment: Which version of `data.table` are you using. 1.9.6 from CRAN or the development version 1.9.7.

Comment: development version 1.9.7

Comment: It's helpful to do `gc(reset=T)` after the above code, to free up 1.5Gb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringr` is newer, based on `stringi` internally and is often [even faster](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/05/05/stringr-1-0-0/).

Also, both stringi and to a lesser extent stringr have multiple variants of each string operation (`fixed/coll/regex/words/boundaries/charclass`) which are optimized for the type of operand.

Try `stri_split_fixed(..., '_')`, it should be very fast.

```
require(stringi)
> system.time( dt[1:1e6, c("LineId", "StationId", "TimeId") := stri_split_fixed(InfoId, "_")] )
   user  system elapsed 
  2.635   0.497   3.379  # on my old machine; please tell us your numbers?
```

Comment: I tried this originally but I couldn't get it to "play nicely" with data.table.  Can you give a working example?

Comment: Added. What specifically do you mean by "play nicely"? Slow? Too much memory? A specific error?

Comment: By "play nicely" I meant that I couldn't get the multi-column update statement to work.  I noticed you originally suggested `str_split_fixed()`.  Is there a reason you changed it to `str_split()`?

Comment: The correct name of the stringi function is `stri_split_fixed()`. Updated that, and the timings.

Comment: This only works for me if I transpose the output of `str_split_fixed` as in the answer by @akrun

Answer (score 2):

One option would be `stri_split` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
dt1 <- copy(dt)
system.time( dt[1:40000000, c("LineId", "StationId", "TimeId") := 
          tstrsplit(InfoId, split="_", fixed=TRUE)] )
#   user  system elapsed 
#  41.20    1.03   42.39 

system.time( dt1[1:40000000, c("LineId", "StationId", "TimeId") := 
     transpose(stri_split(InfoId, fixed = "_"))] )
#   user  system elapsed 
#  28.78    0.98   29.74
```